# Can I use Managed Identity for local development when running Visual Studio as administrator?

Tags: azure, visual-studio, azure-keyvault, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to use Managed Identity to get a connection string from an Azure Key Vault when I run my application locally in Visual Studio 2022. I am signed in as my own azure ad-account and I have the correct role assignment to access secretes in the Key Vault, every thing works as expected.
I am using Azure.Identity and the code looks like this:

`builder.Configuration.AddAzureKeyVault(new Uri($"https://{kvName}.vault.azure.net/"), new DefaultAzureCredential());`

However, in my organization we have to run visual studio as administrator for other reasons. Because of this all the authentication methods it tries fails. I get the following error on startup:

```
Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException: 'DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/defaultazurecredential/troubleshoot
- EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot
- WorkloadIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. The workload options are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/workloadidentitycredential/troubleshoot
- ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. Multiple attempts failed to obtain a token from the managed identity endpoint.
- Visual Studio Token provider can't be accessed at C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\.IdentityService\AzureServiceAuth\tokenprovider.json
- Azure CLI authentication failed due to an unknown error. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/azclicredential/troubleshoot Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/__main__.py", line 39, in <module>
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/__init__.py", line 917, in get_default_cli
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/azlogging.py", line 30, in <module>
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/extension/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\knack/config.py", line 40, in __init__
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\knack/util.py", line 114, in ensure_dir
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\knack/util.py", line 111, in ensure_dir
  File "<frozen os>", line 225, in makedirs
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\config\\systemprofile\\.azure'
- Az.Account module >= 2.2.0 is not installed.
- Azure Developer CLI could not be found.'
```

Is it possible to sign in as me and use Managed Identity locally AND be running Visual Studio as administrator?

I have tried to pass in DefaultAzureCredentialOptions with explicitly set Visual Studio credentials as Chat gpt suggested but no luck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following code to retrieve the secret from the Azure Key Vault with managed identity and successfully retrieved the secret.

**Code :**

***Startup.cs :***

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;

namespace MyApp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            ConfigureAzureKeyVault(services);
            services.AddScoped<IMyService, MyService>();
            ConfigureAuthentication(services);
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }

        private void ConfigureAzureKeyVault(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var keyVaultName = Configuration["AzureKeyVault:VaultName"];
            var keyVaultUri = $"https://{keyVaultName}.vault.azure.net/";

            var client = new SecretClient(new System.Uri(keyVaultUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());
            foreach (var secretName in new[] { "<secret_name>"})
            {
                var secret = client.GetSecret(secretName);
                services.AddSingleton(new ConfigurationBuilder().AddInMemoryCollection(new[]
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>($"KeyVault:{secretName}", secret.Value.Value)
                }).Build());
            }
        }

        private void ConfigureAuthentication(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

            services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            });
            services.AddRazorPages().AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

***MyService.cs :***

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;

namespace MyApp
{
    public class MyService : IMyService
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        public MyService(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        public string GetSecretFromKeyVault()
        {
            var vaultName = _configuration["AzureKeyVault:VaultName"];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(vaultName))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("KeyVault name is not specified in the configuration.");
            }

            var keyVaultUri = $"https://{vaultName}.vault.azure.net/";
            var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(keyVaultUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());
            var secret = client.GetSecret("<secret_name>");
            Console.WriteLine($"Secret value: {secret.Value.Value}");
            return secret.Value.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

***intex.cshmtl :***

```html
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}
<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome to your Home Page!</h1>
    <p>Your secret from Key Vault:</p>
    <p>@ViewBag.Secret</p>
</div>
```

***appsettings.json :***

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "AzureKeyVault": {
    "VaultName": "<keyvault_name>"
  },
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "microsoft.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "<tenantID>",
    "ClientId": "<clientID>",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  }
```

I switched the Azure Web App managed identity **ON** as shown below:

[image]

I assigned the **Key Vault Contributor** role to the Azure Web App and the **Key Vault Reader** role to the Azure AD app in the Azure Key Vault as shown below:

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

I logged in to my own Azure AD account and obtained the Key Vault secret in the browser as shown below:

[image]

***Terminal output:***

[image]

Comment: Thank you for a very detailed and helpful answer. When I tried your solution I realized that my issue was not the fact that I am running VS as admin, it is because I am running my app on IIS locally. The app-pool user is the default ApplicationPoolIdentity and when it is set up like this my developer account that has access to the resources is not available as I understand it. Your answer did not solve my problem but I will mark it as solved since it is a valid answer for the question I posted. :)